# Making a TextView clickable in fragments

Tags: android, textview

Can someone please show me a perfect example of how to make a TextView clickable in a fragment?

Comment: Explain your problem better. `TextView.setClickable()` exists...

Answer (score 4):

Firt of all you have to initialize your TextView

```
  TextView clickTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourIdTextView);
```

Then you can use the setOnClickListener method like this:

```
 clickTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I just clicked my textview!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks man. Worked like a charm. You have my vote!! i was trying to do something like that but made some mistakes and wanted someone to remind me. Thanks!

Comment: Where is my vote ? :)

Comment: I voted you bro. i clicked the up arrow to add a +1 to u. the +1 u see there was from me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on click listener on the textview:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override           
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //...Your Code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the following way to have html a href linked:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

this method is explained in detailed

http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview